# Advance processing multiple Data Frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, data-science

I got a few (15) data frames. They contain values based on one map, but they have fragmentary form.

List of samples looks like `A1 - 3k records, A2 - 6k records. B1 - 12k records, B2- 1k records, B3 - 3k records. C1...` etc.

All files have the same format and it looks that:

```
name     sample    position    position_ID
String1   String1      num1        num1
String2   String2      num2        num2
...
```

All files come from a variety of biological microarrays. Different companies have different matrices, hence the scatter in the size of files. But each of them is based on one common, whole database. Just some of the data from the main database is selected. Therefore, individual records can be repeated between files. I want to see if they are compatible.

**What do I want to achieve in this task?**

I want to check that all records are the same in terms of `name` in all files have the same position and pos_ID values.
If the tested record with the same name differs in values ​​in any file, it must be written to error.csv.
If it is everywhere the same - result.csv.

And to be honest I do not know how to bite it, so I am guided here with a hint that someone is taking good advise to me. I want do it in python. 
I have two ideas.

1. Load in Pandas all files as one data frame and try to write a function filtering whole DF record by record (for loop with if statements?).
2. Open separate all files by python `read file` and adding unique rows to the new list, and when read function would encounter again the same recordName, it would check it with previous. If all rest of values are tha same it will pass it without writing, if no, the record will be written in `error.csv`.

I am afraid, however, that these may not be the most optimal methods, hence asking you for advice and directing me for something better? I have read about numpy, I have not studied it yet, but maybe it is worth it to be in the context of this task? Maybe there is a function that has already been created for this, and I do not know about it?

Can someone help a more sensible (maybe easier) solution?

Comment: `I hope that I was able to clearly outline the problem` - nope. `the same positions or IDs` - why OR? Why are sizes so different? I guess the problem is really about understanding the data and the goal. As for tool `pandas` is all you need. Applying it should be straightforward once you know what you wanna get from the data.

Comment: Ok, thanks edited. AND of course. The sizes are independent of me. The files are simply the result of genetic microarrays that only check specific records from the entire map depending on the company and needs. Therefore, one company has microarrays having 3k records, another 54k and uses different records. So u think i should try first idea? Or meaby should i still use pandas but on separated files?

Comment: I agree with @Poolka, the problem isn't quite clear. As a starting point, I would read all the csvs to a dataframe. I would then I would go `df1["filename"] = 'file1.csv'` so that I can track source of a row. Then I would merge all dataframes into one by using `df_all = pd.concat([df1,df2,etc], axis=1)`. Once in that form, you might be able to do something. I hope thats a good start?

Comment: @erncyp thank u for advice. It's a great idea, I will try it. :) About the post: I edited it, I hope is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a rough idea of where you are going. This is how I would approach it

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")
df1["filename"] ="file1.csv"
df2["filename"] ="file2.csv"

df_total = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1) # stacks them vertically

df_total_no_dupes = df_total.drop_duplicates() # drops duplicate rows

# this gives you the cases where id occures more than once
name_counts = df_total_no_dupes.groupby("name").size().reset_index(name='counts')

names_which_appear_more_than_once = name_counts[name_counts["counts"] > 1]["name"].unique()

filter_condition = df_total_no_dupes["name"].isin(names_which_appear_more_than_once)

# this should be your dataframe where there are at least two rows with same name but different values.
print(df_total_no_dupes[filter_condition].sort_values("name"))
```